# Clean way for many to many relation in doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, many-to-many

Is there a good way for managing this kind of relation in doctrine:

```
class Picture
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
}

class Product
{
    private $id;
    private $pictures;
}

class Article
{
    private $id;
    private $pictures;
}
```

Everytime i read many to many article (even here) i end with

```
class Picture
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="pictures")
     */
    private $products;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="pictures")
     */
    private $articles;
}

class Product
{
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var arraycollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Picture", inversedBy="products")
     */
    private $pictures;
}

class Article
{
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var arraycollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Picture", inversedBy="articles")
     */
    private $pictures;
}
```

What is bother me is :

- in the scope of one article there is no sense that my entity Picture have a attribute $products
- in the scope of one product there is no sense that my entity Picture have a attribute $articles

So yea i can remove my attributes ($products and $articles) but in that case how i write :
Find all picture associated to a article

```
SELECT * 
FROM picture
INNER JOIN article_picture  ON picture.id = article_picture.picture_id
```

I hope i'm clear and Thank you

Comment: It is annoying but it's mostly a result of sql foreign key limitations. Search for "sql foreign key multiple tables" to see some of the workarounds.  But for the most part, it's just something to live with.  If it really bothers you then you could define PictureProductInterface and PictureArticleInterface and typehint against those when appropriate.  Or just close your eyes and forget about it.

Comment: Well thank you.
I will deal with it